# What is my NETWORK SERVICE, LOCAL SERVICE and LOCAL SYSTEM account names?

Tags: sql-server, windows

In SQL Server documentation mentions that in order to install SQL SERVER instance successfully, we need NETWORK SERVICE, LOCAL SERVICE and LOCAL SYSTEM accounts. I am confused right now, what are my account names and passwords for these account?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know to which documentation or which part you refer to but the mentioned accounts are built in accounts and usually there. I have never needed any passwords for these accounts when installing SQL Server, if these even exist. Just go ahead and install it.

Comment: I mean where I could find out what are those user names and passwords in my computer. I looked through the control panel, but could not find them

Comment: They're usually hidden there. Once again, just go ahead and install SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to provide passwords for such accounts, because they are local system credentials that exist on every windows box

More about topic:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/31d57870-1faa-4e14-8527-ce77b1ff40e4/local-service-local-system-or-network-service?forum=sqlsecurity

Comment: SYSTEM, LocalService, and NetworkService are well-known groups that are logged on implicitly with logon IDs 0x03E7, 0x03E5, and 0x3E4.

Comment: Note that the well-known group name is "SYSTEM", not "LOCAL SYSTEM". Some system components (e.g. SCM) support the non-localized English name "LocalSystem", but it's not strictly necessary since "SYSTEM" doesn't get localized, and LSA doesn't support it. LSA does support non-localized "LocalService" and "NetworkService" names, which should be preferred over "LOCAL SERVICE" and "NETWORK SERVICE" (which in a German locale are "Lokaler Dienst" and "Netzwerkdienst").